# XSLT - Detect wraps or line breaks

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010

I have an XSLT stylesheet to transform to HTML

```
<table class="tblOrders">
            <col width="20em" />
            <col width="380em" />
            <col  />
            <col />
            <col width="80em" />
            <col width="30em" />
            <col width="30em" />
            <tr>
              <th>Column1</th>
              <th>Column2</th>
              <th>Column3</th>
              <th>Column4</th>
              <th>Column5</th>
              <th>column6</th>
              <th>column7</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="transfer/items">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Column1"/>
                </td>
                <td class="alnLeft">
                  <font size="-1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Column2"/>
                  </font>
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Column3"/>
                </td>
                <td class="alnRight">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Column4"/>
                </td>
                <td class="alnRight">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Column5"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Column6"/>
                </td>
                <td class="bdrBottom">
                  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>

      <div class="floatRight" style="margin:10em 0em 0em 0em">
        <table id="tblFooterLastPage">
          <tr>
            <th>Initials:</th>
            <td class="bdrBottom">
              <xsl:text>           </xsl:text>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

**Requirement**
The footer should be displayed on each page at the bottom.

**Problem**
Column2 has the potential to word wrap or line break.  I need to display all data.  Note the XSL foreach.  If too many items are in the loop, the footer will display on a new page.  This is not what I want.  I want the footer displayed on the first page, plus each additional page.

**What I think will fix it**
- Create a footer similar to Microsoft Word that always displays.
- Or, if easier, detect where the line breaks occur and count it as 2 lines instead of 1.

Is either potential solution supported by XSLT natively?  What do you suggest?  (If an OO language is required I prefer C#)

Note, this content is designed for print output.

Comment: @Alejandro - This is designed for output to a printer.

Comment: ">Note, this content is designed for print output." Oh no it isn't! It's in HTML. There's no such thing as a page footer in HTML. In fact, there's no such thing as a page.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with XSLT -- in XSLT there isn't any notion of "page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do print, then (X)HTML is not the answer. You could look into [XSL Formatting Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects). But you're in for a bumpy ride.

XSLT does not really know about page and line breaks of the output. It is just a tree transformation language. You shouldn't be worrying about the XSLT functionalities, but instead of those of your output language. I proposed FO above, but you could also try other stuff, like DocBook or MS Word. When you find a nice solution, please leave a comment here, because I'd love to copy it!!!

Comment: @Darren Thomas - I used altova stylevision in the past.  The product worked wonderfully, but its as expensive as it is good.

Comment: I decided on using Apache FOP.  Its free. Works very well.